# Outset of images: Figures surrounding figures

Tags: graphics, subfloats, includegraphics

I am trying to create a figure layout as in

[image]

With `llap`, `raisebox` and `makebox`, I managed to achieve until

[image]

Could someone help/guide me on how to get it as shown in the first figure? Better suggestion(s) is/are also welcome.

Here is the MWE (until what I have):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=1.75in]{example-image-a}\llap{\raisebox{-0.875in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\raisebox{1.75in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}
\includegraphics[height=1.75in]{example-image-b}\llap{\raisebox{-0.875in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\raisebox{1.75in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-.875in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-.875in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{.875in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{1.75in}{\includegraphics[height=0.875in]{example-image-c}}}}
    \caption{My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would a TikZ solution be okay for you?

Comment: @TeXnician Unfortunately no. Because, I infact insert figures from external location and also use `\psfragfig` (by replacing the `\includegraphics`). Another reason is that, when I use `Tikz` in manuscript, copy-editors often globally messes it up. So, sadly, I am refraining from using it.

Comment: Would you accept coffins? They also require an extra package, but do only have the load of expl3 and not TikZ.

Comment: @TeXnician Ofcourse for sure, I will get it a shot (never used it before) :) As a matter of fact, I personally prefer `Tikz`, only because of the copy-editing issues, I am not using it. For fun, please provide the `Tikz` solution as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one very simple version using coffins. Please note that you could optimize it with some loops, but I wanted to show the concept.

The only thing you need to take care of are the main pictures (A and B), because they need to have the same aspect ratio (in the best case same width and height).

To scale this change the dimension value where it currently says `1in`.

[image: figures with coffins]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse} % you could also do that with xcoffins

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_const:Nn \c__raaja_main_height_dim { 1in }

\coffin_new:N  \l__raaja_main_coffin
\coffin_new:N  \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin

\coffin_new:N  \l__raaja_result_coffin

\NewDocumentCommand { \typesetfigures } { m m m }
    {
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__raaja_main_coffin
            {
                \includegraphics [height=\dim_use:N \c__raaja_main_height_dim] { #1 }
                \includegraphics [height=\dim_use:N \c__raaja_main_height_dim] { #2 }
            }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin
            {
                \includegraphics [width=\dim_eval:n { \coffin_wd:N \l__raaja_main_coffin / 4 }] { #3 }
            }
        \coffin_clear:N \l__raaja_result_coffin
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { t }
            \l__raaja_main_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { hc } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { hc } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { hc } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { hc } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_attach:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { t }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { r } { b }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { r } { b }
            \l__raaja_surroundings_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
        \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__raaja_result_coffin { l } { t }
            { 0pt } { 0pt }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \typesetfigures{example-image-a}{example-image-b}{example-image-c}
    \caption{My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @RaajaG You're welcome. Coffins are obviously essential for vivid typesetting :)

Comment: something new to learn :)

Comment: if possible, could you also add the Tikz way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with `makebox`, `risebox` and `overlaps` is by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}\llap{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}\llap{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}
    \caption{My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]