# Part II: Outset of figures with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have figure set that appears with the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}\llap{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[4cm][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}\llap{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}\llap{\makebox[\wd1][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{1cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}\llap{\makebox[0cm][l]{\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}}
    \caption{My caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

like this,

[image]

Now I want to create something like this (preferably through a tikz-based solution):

[image]

> This is a continuation of the question: [Outset of images: Figures surrounding figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444939/outset-of-images-figures-surrounding-figures/444954#444954)

Comment: Is your main concern the gap between the images in the non-`tikz` solution? If so, just add `%` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @Werner Its not just that, now I am planning to import figures through `pgfplots`, so I am not sure whether this trick (the one I am using with makebox) would work. Also, I would like to know how this could be achieved through a `tikz` based solution. The comment made by `TeXnician` in the linked question motivated me to know the `tikz` way though :D Nevertheless, thanks for the `%` tip though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are zillions of possibilities. Here is one of them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt}] (mat) {
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} & 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} & 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} & 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} & 
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} \\ 
};
\node at (barycentric cs:mat-2-2=1,mat-2-3=1,mat-3-2=1,mat-3-3=1)
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
\node at (barycentric cs:mat-2-4=1,mat-2-5=1,mat-3-4=1,mat-3-5=1)
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]